# How can I apply styling to parent element when child is in hovered?

Tags: css

Is this possible with css only? I have the following:

```
 <div class="container">
      <img src=#>
 </div>
```

How do I get `.container` to have a `box-shadow` (and other styling) when and only when img is in the state `:hover`?

Answer (score 1):

As people have stated *there is no CSS parent selector*, for a number of good reasons as stated in the linked duplicate question.

However, with the code you've shown, you can just apply the `hover` pseudo-selector to your parent element and it will achieve *almost* the exact same functionality.

So this:

```
div:hover{
    border:1px solid red
}
```

**Would work *only* because you have a single child**, and would have the issue that if you hover adjacent to the `img` but not directly on it the parent will still have styles applied because its a block element.

You can convert it to `inline-block` to limit this, like so:

```
div{
    display:inline-block;
}
div:hover{
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

However, this will have implications for how other sibling elements to the parent flow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery:

```
$("span").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass("add-class");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("add-class");
  }
);
```

Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/Sv6Av/

You can replace `span` with another tag such as `img`

Comment: I believe the op wants css

Comment: @agconti I'm not sure how to do it with css, though.

Answer (score -1):

Nope. No parent selector in css yet. You will have to resort to js for now. For more explanation read **[this](http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/)**

Comment: That article is 3 years old...

Comment: Please check your own answer before downvoting anybody.